# Minimum element of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have, in Java, a `double[] foo`.

Is there a library function for pulling out the minimum value in this array? I know I can build one, but that's not a good practice if a library function is available. There's nothing in `java.util.Arrays`.

(In C++ we have `std::min_element` etc. and even a new function in C++11 to get the minimum and maximum out at the same time!)

Comment: It's not a good practice when it requires a lot of complicated code lines. That's not your case. Just implement a three easy lines solution.

Comment: Sadly not so. More than 3 lines once you've checked for null, zero length array etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Collections class has such method.

You can write

```
Double[] arr = {0.5,0.7};
System.out.println("min = " + Collections.min(Arrays.asList(arr)));
```

Or to make it shorter :

```
System.out.println("min = " + Collections.min(Arrays.asList(-67,-89,64,34)));
```

Comment: +1 but have reservations about converting `double[]` to `Double[]`

Comment: @SlodgeMonster Arrays.asList on a double array will return a List with a single double[] element, so you must use Double array.

Comment: Thanks, I went for this in the end having changed my `double[]` to a `Double[]`. `Collections.min(Arrays.asList(arr))` is standard Java and doesn't take a deep copy.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming Java 8:

```
double[] arr = { 1.0, 2.0 };
double min = DoubleStream.of(arr)
                         .min()
                         .getAsDouble();
```

Comment: +1, pretty (and is the best answer to my question given that Java 8 is the current standard and I tagged as Java) but don't have Java 8 yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `double[]` to `Double[]` using [ArrayUtils.toObject](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(double[])).
Then convert array to list with [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) and find minimum with [Collections.min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)).

```
double[] d = new double[] {1, 2, 3};
Double minValue = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(d)));
System.out.println(minValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`com.google.common.primitives.Doubles`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html)

```
 double[] arr = { 4.3, 4.9 };
 double min = Doubles.min(arr);
 //OR
 //double min = Doubles.min(4.3, 4.9);
```